# Modify value when getting value of key from a hashtable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

In PowerShell, I have a structure (`HashTable` type) created like so:

```
$Structure = @{
    "KeyOne" = "Value"
    "KeyTwo" = "{Change.This.That}"
    "KeyThree" = "{Change.This.Thing} With Stuff"
    "Change" = @{
        "This" = @{
            "That" = "Another Value"
            "Thing" = "Yogurt"
        }
    }
}
```

The string with the curly brackets are placeholders/tokens for what the actual value should really be, stored in a string format as a reference to the dot notation of some other value within the same object.

I wrote a function to take that tokenized value and retrieve what the actual value is supposed to be that works perfectly fine. Only problem is I have to execute the function every time there is a tokenized value. Is there anyway I can simplify this, specifically instead of running:

```
#I pass structure because I'd rather avoid assuming 
#the hashtable will always be called $Structure
Convert-Token -String $Structure.KeyTwo -Obj $Structure #Another Value
```

is there anyway I can automatically do this by just pulling the bracket notation?

```
#Like this?
$Value = $Structure["KeyThree"]
$Value #Yogurt With Stuff
```

Possible? Not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do something like this:

```
$Selector = $Structure

$Structure = @{
    "KeyOne" = "Value"
    "KeyTwo" = "$($Selector.Change.This.That)"
    "KeyThree" = "$($Selector.Change.This.Thing) with Stuff"
    "Change" = @{
        "This" = @{
            "That" = "Another Value"
            "Thing" = "Yogurt"
        }
    }
}


$Structure["KeyThree"]
```

Comment: Well...that was just too easy